# Database module for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

This **will** get quite clumsy if I continue down the road with this design, so I'm asking you, enlightened ones, is there a way to make this prettier and easier to understand? Primarily the `run`-function (Especially in the `else if` where `self.query` and `self.find` are set), also, I want it to be chain-able, with `.run` being the last function.

```
db = function(dir){
    if(dir[dir.length - 1] == "/") this.dir = dir.slice(0, -1);
    else this.dir = dir;
    return this;
}

db.prototype.table = function(table){
    this.table = table;
    return this;
}

db.prototype.put = function(obj){
    this.put = obj;
    return this;
}

db.prototype.find = function(query){
    this.query = query;
    this.find = "all";
    return this;
}

db.prototype.pluck = function(){
    this.pluck = arguments;
    return this;
}

db.prototype.run = function(callback){
    var self = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));
    for(var key in this){
        if(typeof this[key] != "function" && key != "dir" && key != "table") delete this[key];
    }
    helper.mkdb(self, function(err, created){
        helper.mktbl(self, function(err, created){          
            var docs = [];
            if(self.put){
                helper.put(self, function(err, docs){
                    callback(err, docs);
                })
            }else if(self.query && self.find){
                helper.find(self, function(err, docs){
                    if(err) callback(err);
                    else{
                        self.docs = docs;
                        if(self.pluck){
                            helper.pluck(self, function(err, docs){
                                callback(err, docs);
                            })
                        }else{
                            callback(err, docs);
                        }
                    }
                })
            }else if(self.pluck){
                helper.pluck(self, function(err, docs){
                    callback(err, docs);
                })
            }else callback(new Error("Cannot execute \".run()\" without any functions before it"));
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way, it's not the best though. You can use [nimble](http://caolan.github.io/nimble/) (Or [async](https://github.com/caolan/async), it's basically the same but both larger in size and contain more functions) to do a series of functions, and then check from within the `helper`-class to see if a certain value has been set.

This is my new and improved version of the `run`-function:

```
db.prototype.run = function(callback){
    var self = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));
    for(var key in this){
        if(typeof this[key] != "functions" && key != "dir" && key != "table") delete this[key];
    }
    helper.mkdb(self, function(err, created){
        helper.mktbl(self, function(err, created){          
            self.docs = [];
            nimble.series([
                function(done){
                    if(!self.put) done(err, []);
                    else{
                        helper.put(self, function(err, docs){
                            self.docs = docs;
                            done(err, docs);
                        })
                    }
                },
                function(done){
                    if(!self.query && !self.find) done(err, self.docs || []);
                    else{
                        helper.find(self, function(err, docs){
                            self.docs = docs;
                            done(err, docs);
                        })
                    }
                },
                function(done){
                    if(!self.pluck) done(err, self.docs || []);
                    else{
                        helper.pluck(self, function(err, docs){
                            self.docs = docs;
                            done(err, docs);
                        })
                    }
                }
            ], function(err, res){
                callback(err, helper.lastData(res));
            })
        })
    });
}
```